# Linq to sql with repository for medium size web application

Tags: c#, linq, design-patterns, linq-to-sql, repository

Is creating a Repository pattern implementation on top of Linq to Sql a good design for a medium size public faced web application?

The app only deals with Sql sever backend and it requires rapid development

I really like LINQ2SQL since it's a neat DAL. I thought of EF but it's too much for this project.

Many thanks in advance for the suggestions.

Comment: What is the question? There is no possible answer to this.

Comment: Is creating a Repository pattern implementation on top of Linq to Sql a good design for a medium size public faced web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A large tenet of DDD, from which repository pattern originates, is to create an application which can evolve "easily" over its lifespan. In the future, you may find that Linq2Sql is inadequate for your needs, or (more likely) that the technology was retired (as Linq2Sql would be in favor of EF), etc. Using the repository pattern means you are writing application code against a solid, well-known concept, in an abstract fashion. The actual implementation is hidden from your various application features, meaning you can swap them out in the future as needed.

There are other benefits, too, like allowing a component that uses a repository to be used independently of its environment. Say you have a component that uses a repository, and then you find that you need to be able to use this component in a service to do nightly jobs. You could create a service that uses the same code, but uses an implementation of repository that interacts with a web service, rather than the database. You wrote the code once, just flipped some switches.

Another big reason is unit testing. You don't need to unit test that your ORM or persistence API works, you need to unit test that your application that would otherwise interact with persistence works as expected.

So yeah, I think it's good design.

Comment: How many times do people swap their OR mapper? It never happens. And if it does (which is very unlikely), you need to review and retest the whole app anyway. Abstracting the ORM is guarding against an extremely unlikely cost by paying a very high price.

Comment: Pretty unlikely you will ever swop orms and you lose many features of the orm by abstracting it. You want to abstract data access not the orm.

Comment: @usr I've had to switch from ORM-less to a home-grown ORM to Nhibernate, so yeah, it happens. We're talking about long term application viability. And don't fixate on ORMs; as I stated in my answer, it's not the principal reason to do it. I also forgot another big one: UNIT TESTING.

Comment: @Chev Fortunately, I've not "lost" features of an ORM by using a repository pattern. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Eager loading works differently in all ORMs for example. Some ORMs perform an insert whenever an entity is new'ed, other need to have an InsertOnSubmit call. Abstracting all of that away is a lot of work and leaky. After having used a concrete implementation for years you will have trouble switching because the syntactic contract of an interface is not the whole contract - you rely on a lot of semantics without knowing.

Comment: Also, abstracting over ORMs forces you to only use those features which *all* ORMs have.

Comment: I don't care about what bells and whistles an ORM has. I care about what it does in terms of persistence, which is a select few operations. If you need to dig into specifics of an ORM to facilitate an operation, that's what specifications, named queries, etc. are for. But really, none of that matters because it's all about unit testing anyways. I'm not going to sit here and mock db contexts all day just to know whether or not my controller is calling Save.

Comment: Nhibernate examples like Futures, Eagerloading, transformers would pretty much be lost in repo pattern as they are features tied to NH. I use these extensively.

Comment: I use them, too. Again, repositories abstract basic CRUD which is particularly important in the C, U, and D departments when it comes to things like unit testing. If I need to use the more advanced API features for a query, I have a myriad easy-to-implement options. for example: 1) entity-specific interface with method representing a query, with an NH aware implementation 2) use a ICommand/IQuery architecture that is NH aware (this is my preferred method). Works great, easy to implement, my application is nice and clean but I lose nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your question given in the comments: What would such a repository gain you? L2S already is a "repository". The answer is likely to be no.

How many times do people swap their OR mapper? It never happens. And if it does (which is very unlikely), you need to review and retest the whole app anyway. Abstracting the ORM is guarding against an extremely unlikely cost by always paying a very high price. Not a good trade.

Comment: People refer to Linq2Sql as a data access layer. So there is no point to have a repository? What if I would like to have custom methods outside of the generated LINQ script?

Comment: You absolutely can have those methods as well. The term "repository" is not well defined. Different people mean different things. I made an edit, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Use EF rather, v4.1 and upwards, and skip repository pattern - You are always accessing a db and always accessing ms SQL.

Comment: Isn't EF for much larger applications or used when dealing with multiple backends (not only sql server)?

Comment: No, not at all. EF is really, just the replacement and no need use linq2sql anymore.